# Plumber R, changing 'localhost' to local machine IP as test

Tags: r, server, plumber

I have an R script which is outputs values through an API using Plumber, all runs fine on my local machine (windows 10) when using a 127.0.0.1 or localhost address in the browser, but if I change to use my machines actual IP the browser throws a 'refused to connect' error( I'm running this as a test, before moving everything onto a networked server). Any ideas if this should work? the literature seems to suggest it should...or any tips on what might be preventing this from working?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the 127.0.0.1 by 0.0.0.0 to make your api accessible by your machine ip.

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("api.R")
r$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a firewall configured on your machine that is preventing "external" access on your IP address. You'd need to open up a port in your local firewall in order to allow traffic in, but you're probably better off just deploying to an external server so you don't have to start poking holes in your machine's firewall (a real security concern) just as an experiment.

Also keep in mind that "the machine's actual IP address" can be a little ambiguous. If that's the IP on your local network (for example, `192.168...`, or `172.16...`) then it's probably your machine's firewall like I mentioned above. But if you're using a residential computer and trying to access on your *public* IP, then there is more networking equipment involved (like your router) that would need to be configured.

All that to say, you're probably going to have an easier time just spinning up a DigitalOcean server and trying to run it there (see plumber's `do_provision` function) as you won't have to worry about any of these issues there.